# dictionary item = cell value in last row in column for each grouping

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

This is my code:

```
Dim dBT As Object 'global dictionary

Sub buttonpresscount()

    'constants for column positions
    Const COL_BLOCK As Long = 1
    Const COL_TRIAL As Long = 2
    Const COL_ACT As Long = 7
    Const COL_AOI As Long = 8
    Const COL_RT As Long = 16

    Dim rng As Range, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Dim d, r As Long, k, resBT()

    Set sht = Worksheets("full test")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dBT = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rng = sht.Range("B7:Q" & lastrow)

    d = rng.Value  'get the data into an array

    ReDim resBT(1 To UBound(d), 1 To 1) 'resize the array which will
                                        '  be placed in ColT

    'get unique combinations of Block and Trial and pressedcounts for each
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_ACT) <> "", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("T7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

    'clear dictionary
    dBT.RemoveAll

'count AOI entries
 For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = dBT(k) + IIf(d(r, COL_AOI) = "AOI Entry", 1, 0)
    Next r

    'populate array with appropriate counts for each row
    For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

    'place array to sheet
    sht.Range("U7").Resize(UBound(resBT, 1), 1) = resBT

Call createsummarytable
Call PopSummaryAOI(dBT)

dBT.RemoveAll

   For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
        dBT(k) = Cells(r, COL_RT).Value
    Next r

 'Populate array with last row reaction time for each trial
        For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
        k = d(r, 1) & "|" & d(r, 2)   'create key
        resBT(r, 1) = dBT(k)          'get the count
    Next r

Call PopSummaryRT(dBT)

End Sub
```

I want this line: `dBT(k) = Cells(r, COL_RT).Value` to refer to the value in the last cell in column Q for each trial. At the moment I'm not getting any errors, but the values I want to be printed are not being printed, so I must not be defining the cells' addresses properly.

Here is a screenshot of my data:

[image]

This is where I expect to see the values printed:

[image]

This is the code to print the value to the table:

```
Sub PopSummaryRT(dict)

    Dim sht As Worksheet, k, b, t, f, f2

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("datasummary")

    For Each k In dict

        b = Split(k, "|")(0) 'get block
        t = Split(k, "|")(1) 'get trial
        'find the block
        Set f = sht.Columns(1).Find(what:=b, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'find the trial under that block
            Set f2 = f.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Find(what:=t, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not f2 Is Nothing Then f2.Offset(2, 0).Value = dict(k)
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got fairly sophisticated code here (it clearly wasn't written by a beginner), so why don't you tell what you've done to debug it? Also, while you've showed your inputs and desired outputs, you don't indicate what the *actual output* is, nor explain how it differs from your expectations.

Comment: The actual output is exactly as you see in the second picture. I should be seeing 3893 in cell E4 in the second picture, along with a bunch of different numbers in the rest of the highlighted cells. Most of the code was not written by me, which is why I'm struggling to understand exactly how it is working. The only problem I have is defining which rows go into each key in the dictionary.

Comment: You need to include the code for `PopSummaryRT`

Comment: You mean include it in the question? Edited it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
    k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
    dBT(k) = Cells(r, COL_RT).Value '<--| wrong line
Next r
```

to

```
For r = 1 To UBound(d, 1)
    k = d(r, COL_BLOCK) & "|" & d(r, COL_TRIAL) 'create key
    dBT(k) = d(r, COL_RT) '<--| corrected line
Next r
```

since `Cells` is referencing *all* active worsheet cells, thus ranging from cell "A1" *on*, while your relevant values are collected from cell "B7" on